# I am trying to hide some of row as i written code by matching criteria its working fine but taking too much time to perform..

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
CurrencyManager cm=(CurrencyManager)BindingContext[bindingsource1.Datasource];

 foreach(DataGridviewRow dr in datagridview1.Rows)
{
 datagridview1.SuspendLayout();

  if(dr.Cells[0].Value.Tostring()=="Somevalue")
  {
    dr.Visible=True;
   }
   else
    {
      cm.SuspendBinding();
      dr.Visible=false;
      cm.ResumeBinding();
        }
}
```

this code is working well but its taking much time to perform it.
Is there any way to get speed in this operation???
Is there any Solution for it..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that will do the job and should work faster:

```
datagridview1.SuspendLayout();

foreach(DataGridviewRow dr in datagridview1.Rows)
{
   dr.Visible = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Somevalue";
}

datagridview1.ResumeLayout();
```

as you are modifying only row visibility there is no need to hold binding context. Also suspend layout once before loop and resume it after.

Comment: Thannks gzaxx for fast reply..

i have tried it also but i have above 10000 rows so Iss also not working..